# Compatibility issue between makecookbook and cooking-unit packages

Tags: luatex, latex3, incompatibility

I am writing a cookbook and using the **makecookbook** package and have tried to include the **cooking-units** package. I know that the **makecookbook** uses *LuaTex* and that **cooking-units** uses *LaTeX3*

I have tried switching the TeX compiler to PDFLaTeX and LaTeX. I have tried including, and not, the various packages asked for in the errors.

the error I get is:
Package cooking-units Error: Support package expl3 too old.

I am using the most current version of TeXStudio 4.5.1 and MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.3 (MiKTeX 21.1)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\input{cb-preamble}%part of the makecookbook package

\usepackage{l3kernel}
\usepackage{l3packages}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{cooking-units} %package I want to work with
%\declarecookingunit[tsp] {tsp}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While I'm not sure what the actual problem is (at first sight it just looks like you need to update your packages), I can clear up some terminology confusion: LaTeX3 (i.e., l3kernel and expl3) is the kernel that is used by all compilers (latex, pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex). So there should not be a compatibility problem, when you use LuaLaTeX for makecookbook then you are automatically using (or are able to use) LaTeX3 as well.

Comment: @Marijn  thanks, that did it.